Adding rows based on a condition
I have a dataset that is many thousands of observations long, spanning multiple years. I want to try and write some code that combines some of the observations together and create a thinner dataset. Attached is some example code
ex_df <- data.frame(location = c('park', 'park', 'school', 'cemetery', 'cemetery', 'park'), count = c(50, 50, 4, 9, 26, 10), start = c('7/24/1999', '7/24/1999', '8/9/2000','8/19/2000', '9/2/2001', '9/2/2001'), detected = c('detected', 'detected', 'not detected', 'detected', 'not detected', 'detected')) 
The goal is to have a dataset that looks something like this
ex_df <- data.frame(location = c('park', 'school', 'cemetery', 'cemetery', 'park'), count = c(100, 4, 9, 26, 10), start = c('7/24/1999', '8/9/2000','8/19/2000', '9/2/2001', '9/2/2001'), detected = c('detected', 'not detected', 'detected', 'not detected', 'detected'))
I thought to try and use case_when to try and add the rows together if the date and the location were the same, but case_when to my knowledge only works when you are making a very specific condition, like if I wanted to add all the 'park' observations together, regardless of date.
I also tried to combine using group_by for both the date and location variables and then use sum to combine the 'count' variables, which gives me the desired number, but leaves the leftover observations, which would be another headache to go through and clean up.

With aggregate
aggregate(count ~ ., ex_df, sum)
  location     start     detected count
1     park 7/24/1999     detected   100
2 cemetery 8/19/2000     detected     9
3     park  9/2/2001     detected    10
4   school  8/9/2000 not detected     4
5 cemetery  9/2/2001 not detected    26

